# kivy python widget instance or all widgets

Tags: python, class, object, kivy, instance

Please help me with understanding classes/instances in python. I want to make a few buttons, and change color of the button, when it's clicked. I don't understand why on_touch_down changes the color of all the instances of the class, not the one that is touched. It's difficult for me to find answer because I don't know how to name it, I don't have much experience with objects. Please explain this. Thank you a million.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse

class MemoWidget(Button):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
         self.background_color=[100,100,1,1]

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical',spacing=4)
        m1 = MemoWidget()
        m2 = MemoWidget()
        m3 = MemoWidget()
        root.add_widget(m1)
        root.add_widget(m2)
        root.add_widget(m3)
        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Kivy uses RGBA 0-1 format i.e. 0% to 100% of the value `255` and not the values 0-255 directly.

Comment: Good information, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might think that `on_touch_down` only affects the widget you touch. But it affects all widgets of that class.
So what you might want, is `on_press` or `on_release`, to only affect the widget itself.

```py
class MemoWidget(Button):
    def on_release(self):
         self.background_color=[100,100,1,1]
```

Comment: I understand now, thank you a million for your answer.

Comment: You are wellcome.